# Has Nalo Hopkinson had pets which influenced her writing?

Tags: short-stories, nalo-hopkinson

In at least two of Nalo Hopkinson's short stories that I've read, the main characters are women with an interest in ... *unusual* creatures. Namely, ["Can't Beat 'Em"](https://uncannymagazine.com/article/cant-beat-em/) (Marisella keeps a 'glup', a sort of sink drain monster, so that she can consume it to become immortal) and ["A Raggy Dog, a Shaggy Dog"](https://www.apex-magazine.com/a-raggy-dog-a-shaggy-dog/) (Tammy loves her orchids, and keeps a rat which is slowly being taken over by an orchid growing inside it). I'm curious whether this element of her writing was inspired by any unusual pets of her own.

**What pets has Nalo Hopkinson had? Did they influence her writing at all?**

Comment: Calling the "glup" a pet is a bit of a stretch; those glups are a kind of pest and Marisella was not "keeping" it in the drain but trying to get rid of it. (At least until the end of the story.)

Comment: @Christophe Yeah, it's the end of the story I'm thinking of. Maybe not exactly a *pet*, but she seems to feel an unusual amount of affection for that type of creature, like Tammy in the other story.

Comment: Her affection goes to the plumber. Marisella is just thinking of how she might cook the glup and whether she should invite the plumber or not.